# Proguard Breaks Database Connection

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, proguard

My application uses a [`database`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) based on [`sqlite-jdbc`](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads). When I generate the runnable [`jar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file, connecting to my database works fine however if I let [`Proguard`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) process my application, it breaks the database connection.

The following code establishes a connection with the database file's path submitted. When using Proguard, the message "Got connection!" is never printed hence [`getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) is stuck.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

private void loadDatabase(String databaseName) throws SQLException
{
    String databaseLibrary = "jdbc:sqlite:";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Getting connection...");
    Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseLibrary
            + databaseName);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Got connection!");

    // ...
}
```

Only if the `Shrink` and [`Obfuscate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) options are disabled in Proguard the database connectivity does not break after processing.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed and why this happens?

Comment: The SQLite library should not be obfuscated, and better leave out `Class.forName`. As you do not need the SQLite library for compilation remove any compile-time dependency.

Comment: @JoopEggen:
So I just exclude `sqlite` via `-keep class org.sqlite.** { *; }`, is this how it should be done? It works at least :)

Comment: Yes I think so. The latest JDBC specifies the original class name in a Java SPI file or so (- no longer Class.forName needed.) So obfuscation plays havoc.